# Pending Intent with alarm Manager (Notifications)

Tags: android, notifications, android-alarms

I'm using Alarm manager for getting local notifications here is my code, it is running perfectly and all alarms and notifications are coming at right time. But I want that when I click on notification it should go to class `Act_Remainder` in my app. 
How to solve this issue?

```
Intent intent1 = newIntent(this.getApplicationContext(), Act_Remainder.class);

    if(intent!=null){
        userID = intent.getStringExtra("UserID");
        userID1 = intent.getStringExtra("UserID1");
        ID = intent.getIntExtra("ID", 0);
    }

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ioc_icon,
    userID1, System.currentTimeMillis());

    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent =     PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: Thannx to all for editing my question but can anyone help me to solve this issue?????????

Comment: replce PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT to PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: @Lucky i tried this also but it is sending one blank notification at unknown time,means after 1hr or half an hour...this time is not decided

Comment: okks this may be the problem of getting Null notification_id which is passing you as current time. so what can you do put a another condition for checking if   "(notification_id)== null" just call the alarmManager.cancel(notification_id) ; in you services class by passing same  notification_id ...hope it will solve you problem..

Comment: @Lucky ok but it is not sending that blank notification when i m using FLAG_ONE_SHOT but only when i m using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR simply use this...

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

```
    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(                      this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),Act_DashBord.class);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.applogo_57x57,
            "Muslim Companion", System.currentTimeMillis());

    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    int id = 0;
    if (intent != null) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("Message");
        id = intent.getIntExtra("Id", 0);
    }           

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "Muslim Companion", message, pendingNotificationIntent);
    long count = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(id), notification);


    mManager.cancel(Integer.valueOf(id));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing it was copy and paste problem from my workspace.